# Type narrowing object properties with a function

Tags: typescript, narrowing

I have a complicated type with many nested properties. I want type narrowing. This seems to work for basic primitives, but when an object is involved, TS cannot seem to narrow the properties using the same principles.

```
type Test = {
    property: string | null
}

const propIsNotNull = (data: Test): boolean => {
    return (data.property !== null)
}

const testData: Test = {
    property: 'nonull'
}

if (propIsNotNull(testData)) {
    console.log(testData.property.toUpperCase())
    //          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // 'testData.property' is possibly 'null'.(18047)
}
```

I can of course change it to the following, but it makes the code harder to read

```
if (testData.property !== null) {
    console.log(testData.property.toUpperCase())
}
```

I don't really want to make a new type just so I can use a type guard. I feel like I am missing something fundamentally simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function without a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-type-predicates) will never have any narrowing capabilities. You also don't need a *new* type just to make a type predicate. There are multiple ways to *reuse* the type and just *modify* the part that you are checking.

One possible way would look like this:

```
const propIsNotNull = (data: Test): data is Test & { 
    property: Exclude<Test["property"], null> 
} => {
    return (data.property !== null)
}
```

The type predicate signals to the caller that `data` is of type `Test` and that the property `property` is not `null` if the condition is `true`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8BQVtTAJwHtI9QAuKRPASwDsBzKAHyhoFcAbdjAXwwwGMCNRLkJgAkvAByBYFI7sUUABQATAIbB15OIgCU5DVqhV4sBEgBk6KFhz4iEEiHIBRAB792rVRAA8usAA2gBEDsSgIQC6ADQsCgB8ttwoSZg4UHgQwKx4NCpG6gB04U6gUACEyKhsnHo8fILCSMAWACKa2uYiqOn2YmUuUADkNEIKww0YVABmKuGSMnIKyq2IHVp6euh22E3wBOwQRewEdKvtnSUDzkXABACqYMQAwurwEMpbPEA)

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but can you answer why this seems to work without a type predicate? [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4qIE4EsB2BzKAPlNgK4A2ZAsAFA0DGA9tolGOg2AJLwByDwPcmRRQAFABMAhsEkAuWAmABKeQCMGDMhEnYUAPigBvGlFNR0EYCXS6J0yVACEyVKQpKaAXxr0mLYIoAIvbycCyoAOTYTEIRPtSYAGZibBzcfAJCogGIwTJKSkYmZozMmhAAdGQMuNlB9hXADACqYJDoAMKS8BCiBV5AA)

Comment: The same reason as why this works: https://tsplay.dev/NB4kzW. Control flow analysis can see that *just* assigned a value to `testData` which is not null. The function has no effect there at all

Comment: That's a great answer! Thanks.